# Can't access variables in imported .java classes in .jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, import

I have a problem with importing a class into a .jsp file. When I try to import the program keeps working, but I can't access the variables. I am trying to import the GameServlet.java class into game.jsp.

import like:

```jsp
<%@ page import="com.example.TextGame, com.example.GameServlet, java.util.Scanner" %>
```

for some reason it doesn't work

The structure of the project is:

- demo

  - src

    - main

      - java

        - com.example

          - GameServlet.java
          - TextGame.java
      - resources
      - webapp

        - WEB-INF

          - web.xml
        - game.jsp
        - index.jsp
  - target
  - pom.xml

My .xml look like this:

**xml file**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <!-- Servlet Mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myservlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**java** classes:

**GameServlet.java**

```java
package com.example;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet("/GameServlet")
public class GameServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String playerName = (String) session.getAttribute("playerName");

        session.setAttribute("game", new TextGame());

        response.sendRedirect("game.jsp");
    }
}
```

**TextGame.java**

```java
package com.example;

public class TextGame {
    private String currentLocation;

    public TextGame() {
        this.currentLocation = "start";
    }

    public String getCurrentLocation() {
        return currentLocation;
    }

    public void handlePlayerInput(String input) {
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("go north")) {
            currentLocation = "north_location";
        } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("go south")) {
            currentLocation = "south_location";
        }
    }
}
```

**jsp** files:

**game.jsp**

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="com.example.TextGame, com.example.GameServlet, java.util.Scanner" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Текстова гра - Гравець: ${sessionScope.playerName}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Вітаємо, ${sessionScope.playerName}!</h1>

    <p>Ви знаходитесь в ${sessionScope.game.currentLocation}.</p>

    <form action="GameServlet" method="post">
        <label for="playerInput">Введіть команду:</label>
        <input type="text" id="playerInput" name="playerInput" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Виконати">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.jsp**

```xhtml
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Текстова гра</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="GameServlet" method="post">
        <label for="playerName">Введіть ваше ім'я:</label>
        <input type="text" id="playerName" name="playerName" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Почати гру">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've trying import like:

```jsp
<%@ page import="com.example.TextGame, com.example.GameServlet, java.util.Scanner" %>
```

or:

```jsp
<%@ page import="com.example.TextGame" %>
<%@ page import="com.example.GameServlet" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Scanner" %>
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `import` that you tried does not solve the problem that you describe/that is visible by looking at your code. You better remove these unnecessary reports.

The GameServlet is accessing the data from the HttpSession, but the data was never stored there.

Look at how a user would go through the application. Initially he is on index.jsp which makes the browser display a form. The user fills in his username, then upon submit that username is sent to the next url: GameServlet

The GameServlet can now read the submitted username as `request.getParameter("playerName")` and store it as `getHttpSession().setAttribute("playerName", request.getParameter("playerName"))`

Only after storing the attribute in the session subsequent pages/servlets will be able to read it again. So you either have to change your GameServlet, or create another servlet/JSP that stores the playername in the session.

Comment: @queeg Yes, you figured out that a variable should put into session. But you didn't solve the main problem: Why OP tried to import classes to the JSP. Second, you didn't read the code thoroughly to understand a business logic of the application. Your code is useless because it unknown how to apply. The workflow of the application is wrong. It will never work as expected. This and other summarize mistakes makes you answer too bad.

Comment: Well I cannot 'solve' the problem why the OP tried to import classes. But I edited my answer so this is taken into account. Like it more now?

Comment: OP imported classes trying to  solve the problem of accessing variables in EL expressions, but OP don't know how to access them or intended access them in scriptlets, anyway it's wrong try, and we should lead OP to the right direction. Because OP can't/shouldn't access the class variables in the imported classes. This is the main idea. Then comes the second problem EL expressions didn't work, then third problem direct to JSP, then fourth problem with business logic, etc. Everything you should fix, when providing a consisting answer.